# Salesforce Extension Pack not installing

Tags: salesforce, vscode-extensions

Since the 15th Feb 2024 the Salesforce extensions in my local vscode instance are just stuck on installing when i started VsCode.
I have tried uninstalling all of them (the SF ones), via

code --list-extensions

code --uninstall-extension ID

which worked to uninstall but then when I go to reinstall the Salesforce Extension Pack it just stays on 'Installing'.
Non-SF extensions are fine. I am running SF CLI 2.23.20.

I am running Win10 with the following
Version: 1.86.2 (user setup)
Commit: 903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda
Date: 2024-02-13T19:40:56.878Z
Electron: 27.2.3
ElectronBuildId: 26908389
Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
Node.js: 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

VS Code version: Code 1.86.2 (903b1e9d8990623e3d7da1df3d33db3e42d80eda, 2024-02-13T19:40:56.878Z)
OS version: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

I have tried uninstalling all of them (the SF ones), via
code --list-extensions
code --uninstall-extension ID
which worked to uninstall but then when I go to reinstall the Salesforce Extension Pack it just stays on 'Installing'.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the extensions eventually got installed after several hours.